# How to read npm module in browser?

Tags: npm, webpack

I get one npm module via ajax. I try to `eval` this respond, but after this I can't find It in any places. I'm looking for in `window` or `this`, even `module` - but this undefinded. How to correctly eval npm module in browser?

PS. I know I should do It via `require`, but, unfortunately, I need to do in browser without require. :(

Comment: You tagged this `webpack` … so read the documentation for webpack?

Answer (score -1):

@kspacja npm is part of the Node.js framework as as far as I'm aware it's not possible to run an npm module in the browser. Perhaps you should use Angular.js as your browser framework? Also please research the MEAN stack.

Comment: A lot of NPM modules _can_ be used in the browser, since they are plain JS that doesn't rely on Node-specifics.